# Bipartite allocation with minimum cost

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Given two vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$. The vertices in $V_2$ have a limitation on the maximum degree of each vertex being $K$. I need to find an allocation algorithm such that every pair of vertices in $V_1$ is interconnected via a vertex in $V_2$ i.e $X \leftrightarrow Y \leftrightarrow Z$ , where $X,Z \in V_1$ and $Y \in V_2$.

The goal is to find an allocation that minimizes the distances between all such pairs in $V_1$. The distance is measured as : $\; dist(X, Y) + dist(Y, Z)\;$. The distances are provided beforehand.  I kind of came up with an algorithm, but it doesn't guarantee optimality. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

In the above image, we can see that all pairs from the left vertex set are connected to each other via one from the other set. Now from the image it is seen that for a pair, there can be multiple paths eg : (3,4) "looks like " it is connected via 6 as well as 7. But the pair (3, 4) was allocated to 6 and not 7. The edge 3-7 and 4-7 simply exist because of other pairs like (2, 3) and (2, 4) that were allocated to 7. Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: Several things are unclear to me...  (1) Are you saying all the $dist(X,Y)$ are given but you have to choose whether to actually place an edge there?  (2) If multiple $Y$s connect $X$  to $Z$ do you count only the "best" $Y$?  (3) Are you trying to minimize the total distance, summed across all $(X,Z)$ pairs?

Comment: @antkam 1) yes, the problem is all about whether to place the edge there or not.
2) Yes, only the best Y 3) yes, exactly.
Basically, I want to take each pair (X, Z) and then have an algorithm that tells me which 'Y' to connect them to.

Comment: This is a rather interesting problem.  What is the context?  Research?  Homework?  I.e. how did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @antkam thanks for the response. It is a subpart of my research. I am finding it challenging to tackle this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are typical values of $|V_1|, |V_2|, K$?  For small $K$ this almost feels like a typical NP-complete assignment problem (even before the distance minimization part).  Unrelatedly, do you have access to an integer-programming solver?  I'd think this can be cast as a (potentially large) integer-program, but I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: The values of V1, V2 and K are all under 100. An approximation/heuristic would do good. I do have access to an LP solver, but it is part of the research to come up with an approximation/heuristic for comparision with the LP solver.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to solve this as a balanced transportation problem. Here I assume $K$ is even, since for every edge entering a node in $V_2$, there must be an edge leaving a node in $V_2$. Let $S=V_1\times{V_1}$ (*i.e.* the set of all pairs of nodes in $V_1$). Each node in $S$ has a supply of $1$. In addition, add a dummy supply node $s_0$ with supply $\tfrac{1}{2}|V_2|K-|V_1|^2$ (which I assume is positive, or your problem is infeasible). The set of demand nodes is $V_2$, each with demand $K/2$. For each $(i,j)\in{S}$ and $k\in{V_2}$, the cost to ship from $(i,j)$ to $k$ is $\operatorname{dist}(i,k)+\operatorname{dist}(j,k)$. For all $k\in{V_2}$, the cost to ship from $s_0$ to $k$ is $0$.

Assuming the distances are integral (which can be accomplished to arbitrary approximation accuracy with scaling), this balanced transportation problem will provide an optimal solution to your problem in polynomial time (and is quite efficient in practice).

Comment: This isn't quite right, if I understand the question correctly.  In your approach you could e.g. use supplies $(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)$ to ship to a $y \in V_2$ when $K=3$.  But mapping back to the original graph this would require $6$ edges to $y$ when it is constrained to have only $K=3$ edges.

Comment: @antkam Yes I think you’re right. Demand nodes should have demand value $\lfloor{K/2}\rfloor$.

Comment: @DavidM. Thanks for your response. The thing is that i only need an optimal/suboptimal/approximate allocation algorithm for the nodes in set V1 to V2. I don't understand how I would proceed to actually solve the balanced transportation problem which you suggested. Sorry for my inability to grasp what you are suggesting.

Comment: @DavidM. Even if you use $K/2$, this doesn't model one (important?) aspect of the OP's problem, namely, if you attach $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ to $y \in V_2$, you actually get $(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)$ also, because the actual edges are $1y, 2y, 3y, 4y$.

Comment: @antkam I may be misunderstanding you or the OP, but it’s not clear what the problem is. If you connect the node $(1,2)\in{S}$ to $y\in{V_2}$, we interpret that to mean you connect $1\to{y}\to2$ in the original problem. Each supply node in my proposed balanced transportation problem corresponds to a pair of nodes in the original graph. What am I missing?

Comment: @Aizen No worries. Are you familiar with linear programming? The algorithms for balanced transportation problems are specialized versions of the algorithms used to solve linear programs.

Comment: @Aizen I’m definitely confused so I will remove this answer. If you have time, perhaps you can add a small example to your post (for the slow people like me!)

Comment: @DavidM. I am extremely sorry for my typing error. Deleted and typed again. Please do see if this is understandable.
If we attach (1,2) and (3, 4) to y∈V2 . then it only means that the pairs (1,2) and (3,4) talk to each other via 'y'. Even though there is a path between say (1,3) or (2,4) via 'y', (because 1,2,3,4 all area connected to 'y'); we only compute the cost between "pairs that were assigned" explicitly. (1,3) or (2,4) wasn't explicitly assigned to 'y', (we only assigned (1,2) and (3,4))